# Examples of generating the same topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm teaching myself topology using a book I found. The question below is from the text. Then there are two additional questions that I am curious about. Please let me know if I'm doing it correct. 

..................................................

> Show that the discrete metric and the Euclidean metric generate the same topology on the set $\mathbb{Z}$ the integers.

Given:

> Suppose $M$ is a set and $d, d'$ are two different metrics of $M$. $d$ and $d'$ generate the same topology on $M$ if and only if for every $x \in M$ and every $r>0$, there exist positive numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $B_{r_1}^{(d')}(x) \subseteq B_{r}^{(d)}(x)$ and $B_{r_2}^{(d)}(x) \subseteq B_{r}^{(d')}(x)$.

Let: d= discrete metric, d'=Euclidean metric
If $r=3$, and $x = 5$, then $r_1 = r_2 = 0.5$ will satisfy above. 
$$B_{r_1}^{(d')}(x)=\{5\}$$
$$B_{r}^{(d)}(x)=\mathbb{Z}$$
 $$B_{r_2}^{(d)}(x)=\{5\}$$ 
$$B_{r}^{(d')}(x)=\{3,4,5,6,7\}$$
If $0<r<1$ then all 4 sets are {5}. In either case the open balls are subsets as required to have the same topology. The same argument can be made for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and any positive r.

Now, I have my own variation.

> Does that the discrete metric and the Euclidean metric generate the same topology on the set $\mathbb{R}$ the reals?

Let: d= discrete metric, d'=Euclidean metric
If $r=3$, and $x = 5$, then $r_1 = r_2 = 0.5$ 
$$B_{r_1}^{(d')}(x)=(4.5,5.5)$$
$$B_{r}^{(d)}(x)=\mathbb{R}$$
 $$B_{r_2}^{(d)}(x)=\{5\}$$ 
$$B_{r}^{(d')}(x)=(2,8)$$
This does satisfy the criteria to have the same topology. However what if $r=0.5, r_1=r_2=0.01$
$$B_{r_1}^{(d')}(x)=(4.99,5.01)$$
$$B_{r}^{(d)}(x)=\{5\}$$
 $$B_{r_2}^{(d)}(x)=\{5\}$$ 
$$B_{r}^{(d')}(x)=(4.5,5.5)$$

No matter how small $r_1$ is, it will never be the case that: $B_{r_1}^{(d')}(x) \subseteq B_{r}^{(d)}(x)$. Since that is not true, they do not generate the same topology.

> Does that the discrete metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{Z}$ generate the same topology?

Let: d= discrete metric, d'=Euclidean metric
If $r=3$, and $x = 5$, then $r_1 = r_2 = 0.5$
$$B_{r_1}^{(d')}(x)={5}$$
$$B_{r}^{(d)}(x)=\mathbb{R}$$
 $$B_{r_2}^{(d)}(x)=\{5\}$$ 
$$B_{r}^{(d')}(x)=\{3,4,5,6,7\}$$
If $0<r<1$ then all 4 sets are {5}. In either case the open balls are subsets as required to have the same topology. The same argument can be made for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ and any positive r.

Therefore, they do generate the same topology.

..................................................
please let me know if this is all correct.

Comment: The discrete metric on $\mathbb R$ and the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb Z$ _do not_ generate the same topology, since they are on different sets.

Comment: So, for typologies to be the same, they must be referring to the same set?

Comment: the third q, as stated,is flawed. it refers to a topologies on different sets.  the rest is ok. ..you might shorten it by noticing that on Z, the open balls of radius 1 or less with the discrete or euclidean metric, are the same sets, so of course the topologies are the same.

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky Yes. (These two topologies are especially different in that they have different cardinalities.)

Comment: A topological space is a set S together with a family T of some or all of the subsets of S, called a topology on S, subject to a few requirements. (check the definition)...It is common (mal)practice to refer to " the space S", omitting to mention T.